# Flex set-difference

Tags: flex-lexer

I would like to know how do I define a set difference (A/B) in flex , thank you

Comment: I'm actually not sure what you're asking about.  What is a set difference?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com, Perhaps he's talking about this: http://math.comsci.us/sets/difference.html.

Comment: Yes Jason is right , thank you Jason

Comment: What kind of data do you have? or is this something more general?

Comment: Do you have any sample code or data? Do you just want to have 2 lists where items in List A aren't in List B?

Comment: I am taking about "http://flex.sourceforge.net/manual/", I intend to define regular expression of set difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean the difference of two character classes, flex provides
the `{-}` operator.

This operator's explanation will be found in [the Flex manual chapter on Patterns](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html).

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can do this type of thing quite easily with ActionLinq (ActionLinq.org)

```
var A:IEnumerable = Enumerable.from([1,2,3,4]);
var B:IEnumerable = Enumerable.from([2,3,4,5]);

var diff:Array = A.except(B).toArray();
```